# Android pinch zoom. Focus point / image shifting when pinching

Tags: android, android-canvas, multi-touch

I've been working on creating a custom view with a really slick pinch zoom. So far I have got the zooming and panning working, but when I pinch zoom on a different area of the screen the image moves to the opposite position the screen.

For example if the image is on the left and I pinch zoom on the left, the image will shift to the right.

I'm sure I am making a simple error somewhere, but I can't for the life of me figure out where the problem is. I've tried masses of changes over the last few days and spent hours searching through SO to no avail.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
private class PinchView extends View {

    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
    private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;
    private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;

    // The ‘active pointer’ is the one currently moving our object.
    private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

    private Drawable mIcon;
    private float mPosX;
    private float mPosY;

    private float mLastTouchX;
    private float mLastTouchY;


    private float focusX;
    private float focusY;



    public PinchView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mIcon = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        mIcon.setBounds(0, 0, mIcon.getIntrinsicWidth(), mIcon.getIntrinsicHeight());

        // Create our ScaleGestureDetector
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        // Let the ScaleGestureDetector inspect all events.
        mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);

        final int action = ev.getAction();
        switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            final float x = ev.getX()/mScaleFactor;
            final float y = ev.getY()/mScaleFactor;

            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;
            mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0);
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            final int pointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
            final float x = ev.getX(pointerIndex)/mScaleFactor;
            final float y = ev.getY(pointerIndex)/mScaleFactor;

            // Only move if the ScaleGestureDetector isn't processing a gesture.
            if (!mScaleDetector.isInProgress()) {
                final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
                final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

                mPosX += dx;
                mPosY += dy;

                invalidate();
            }

            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;

            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
            final int pointerIndex = (ev.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) 
                    >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
            final int pointerId = ev.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
            if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
                // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
                // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
                final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                mLastTouchX = ev.getX(newPointerIndex)/mScaleFactor;
                mLastTouchY = ev.getY(newPointerIndex)/mScaleFactor;
                mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
            }



            break;
        }
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.save();

     //   canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
        canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, focusX, focusY);
        canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);
        mIcon.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }

    private float lastFocusX = -1;
    private float lastFocusY = -1;

    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {



        @Override
        public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

        //  float x = detector.getFocusX();
        //  float y = detector.getFocusY();

            lastFocusX = -1;
            lastFocusY = -1;


            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

            focusX = detector.getFocusX();
            focusY = detector.getFocusY();

            if(lastFocusX == -1) lastFocusX = focusX;
            if(lastFocusY == -1) lastFocusY = focusY;


            mPosX += (focusX - lastFocusX);
            mPosY += (focusY - lastFocusY);




            // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
            mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 5.0f));

          lastFocusX = focusX;
          lastFocusY = focusY;

            invalidate();
            return true;
        }



    }
}
```